# How can software components report (missing) features?

Tags: c, terminology

A software component provides features. Some of these features have dependencies (such as hardware or external libraries). 
I'm thinking primarily of portable software components that are tightly coupled to hardware such as I2C (not all I2C peripherals have the same features and software emulation of I2C has limitations).
If missing features in those dependencies cannot be emulated this breaks the feature and it needs to be made known to the software using this component.
The software can then provide a workaround or report the error to a higher layer.
As an embedded firmware engineer I've had many situations where strange limitations or missing features of drivers only became apparent during testing. It was simply not documented and was not communicated in software either.

I can think of three techniques to report missing features or limitations:

1. Do provide an interface to the functions, but simply return an errorcode or raise an exception. Downside: after the fact.
2. Use constants to communicate features (FEATURE_X_SUPPORTED) and limitations (MAX_FREQUENCY). Downsides: the list of features can be quite large and the code using the component must be aware of all features it uses. To my knowledge there is no standardized way to do this.
3. Document it.

What is the official terminology for this problem? I recall hearing about a concept named something like "feature listing". What other techniques are used to solve the problem of compatibility?

Comment: I don’t understand why solution (2) necessarily complicates the code. With proper separation of interfaces this seems to me to be clearly the preferred solution in most cases.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I've clarified the downside. The list of features could be very large and would probably not be exhaustive. A blacklist of missing features would not be much better. The software using the component must check for all used features.

Comment: and then when someone implements a new device with a new feature, you get to replace all the drivers for all the old hardware with new drivers that mark the new feature as missing.

Comment: I2C is a serial bus; which means that the I2C controller's driver should have low level transport (e.g. "send byte/s" and "receive bytes/s") and nothing else; and drivers for peripherals on the I2C bus should do what makes sense for that type of device (while relying on the I2C controller driver to send/receive bytes). A "generic I2C peripheral driver" is a massive design failure that will cause major "feature not supported" problems everywhere. This would be as silly as trying to have a generic USB peripheral driver that tries to make an ethernet controller behave like a mouse.

Comment: Note: If my guess is right (you're trying to make very different types of I2C peripherals support the same interface) then I'd be tempted to suggest that the "official" terminology might be "god object" ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object ).

Comment: @Jasen Exactly! Maintenance would be a challenge. You could come up with a clever way to add warnings for 'marks' that are new to the software.

Comment: @Brendan The problem is that I2C can do more than just send and receive bytes (some are within the standard, others are expansions). For instance: some protocols like SM-bus requires slave-mode-arbitration, multi-address slaves, and timeouts. Sending and receiving can be done in both master and slave mode. Some protocols require switching between master and slave mode. Some protocols require the ability to nack a specific byte, while not all peripherals offer that ability. Peripherals or boards don't always support all of the 5 different speed modes.

Comment: @Brendan Good point. That is what I want to avoid. I want an elegant way to have software detect (and potentially workaround) compatibility issues without people having knowledge about a specific combination of board, peripheral, low level driver and all their features. Not just I2C.